# Remove LF inside specific field and nowhere else

Tags: javascript, mongodb, bash, newline

I have been asked to clean data up in a MongoDB collection we have to stored addresses and generic customer contact data.

Data contains occasionally carriage returns that tend to break the load process when I push the data into a MySQL table. My code uses Javascript to do `a replace(/\n//g, '')` on the critical fields. However, the data dump still shows up messy as shown here:

```
"_id"|"UserID"|"PhoneNumber"|"Source"|"PrivateLabelID"|"OptOut"|"Blocked"|"Deleted"|"Note"|"CreatedAt"|"UpdatedAt"|"FirstName"|"LastName"|"Email"|"Custom1"|"Custom2"|"Custom3"|"Custom4"|"Custom5"|"GroupIDs"
"5e37169df3369f47583355dc"|"127342"|"8645169963"|"1"|"1"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"Timothy.. I mainly buy in the SW area of Florida. Please send me what you have"|"1580668573"|"1580668573"|"Lee"|"Burnside"|"clemsonworldentertainment@gmail.com"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"[object Object]"
"5e3712c6958b2b1896070f2b"|"127342"|"8452063505"|"1"|"1"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"Yes I am looking in the lower to central Florida market. Multi family units."|"1580667590"|"1580667591"|"Daniel "|"Lepore"|"daniellepore@icloud.com"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"[object Object]"
"5e37107f61befe0bea740cfa"|"127342"|"3867770002"|"1"|"1"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"He's with Habib
His last name is not Thompson that Habib name"|"1580667007"|"1580667007"|"Thompson"|""|""|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"[object Object]"
"5e370e08853f2702e40828fa"|"127342"|"4073712312"|"1"|"1"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"Indeed we are looking for Buy, Fix and Sell and strong rentals including duplexes, triplexes etc.
"|"1580666376"|"1580666376"|"Gisela "|"Escobar"|"jbetfinancial@gmail.com"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"[object Object]"
"5e3709f351798f62ea228e08"|"127342"|"4077774697"|"1"|"1"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"undefined"|"Yes I am buying in that area or any area in Florida if the numbers are right
only in Flipping houses
```

The "Note" field is the challenge here. What I run `cat --show-all filename`, I see the LF "$" character at the end of each record **as well as inside the "Note" field.**

I tried `tr '\n' ' ' <filename` but it removes all the LF characters. Is there a way to remove the LF characters only inside the "Note" field?

PS: [Raw data file](https://github.com/passemoilesel/furry-couscous/blob/master/contacts.mongo) (9 lines) if you want to check for yourself.

Comment: you might need to explain this!

Comment: we need to know what the actual character is in the middle of the field ... can't tell at this point if we're talking dos or unix file; I'd suggest putting the field in question into its own file, leave a few characters before and after the non-printable character and then run the file through `od`, eg, assume sample data is in `test.dat`, so run `od -c test.dat` and place the entire output in your question.

Comment: @markp I assume he's looking for a regex that replaces \n with space. But doesn't apply to "\n

Comment: @user171558, sure, remove one (or more) embedded cr/lf's ....

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you are trying to remove `\n` unless there is a quote sign before it

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/[^"]\n/ /g' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- the embedded return/linefeed shows up as a single `\n` when the file is run through `od`
- there may be more than one embedded `\n` in the file
- once the embedded `\n`(s) are removed then each line should have 20 fields (delimiter = `|`)

For this example I'm going to work with a smaller file of just 6 fields per line.  The comments are only added here for documentation purposes, ie, the comments don't exist in the actual data file:

```
$ cat abc.dat
f1|f2|f3|f4                    # line1 part1
f4|f5|f6                       # line1 part2
g1|g2|g3|g4 g4|g5|g6           # line2
h1|h2|h3|h4 h4|h5|h6           # line3
i1|i2|i3|i4                    # line4 part1
f4|i5|i6                       # line4 part2
j1|j2|j3|j4 j4|j5|j6           # line5
k1|k2|                         # line6 part1
k3|k4 k4|k5                    # line6 part2
|k6                            # line6 part3
l1|l2|l3|l4 l4|l5|l6           # line7
```

Instead of trying to focus on stripping out the embedded `\n`, we're just going to append together lines (w/ a space in between) until we have 6 fields and then we'll add our own `\n` on the end.

One `awk` solution (again, comments are only for documentation purposes):

```
awk -F"|" '
BEGIN          { prevNF=0    }                             # preset our previousNF to 0
(NF+prevNF)==6 { printf "%s\n",$0 ; prevNF=0 ; next      } # if we have 6 fields then print current line and terminate with a \n, then skip to next line of input
               { printf "%s " ,$0 ; prevNF=(prevNF+NF-1) } # otherwise print the line terminated with a space and save our current NF minus 1 (to account for fact current last field == first field of next line)
END            { printf "\n" }                             # one final \n to get us onto a new/blank line
' abc.dat
```

Running the above against my `abc.txt` file gives us:

```
f1|f2|f3|f4 f4|f5|f6
g1|g2|g3|g4 g4|g5|g6
h1|h2|h3|h4 h4|h5|h6
i1|i2|i3|i4 f4|i5|i6
j1|j2|j3|j4 j4|j5|j6
k1|k2| k3|k4 k4|k5 |k6
l1|l2|l3|l4 l4|l5|l6
```

Here's a [bash fiddle](http://tpcg.io/CwWVEcdf)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an aggregation in MongoDB to make the change before exporting?

If you need to leave the original data untouched, create a new collection with the modified data:

```
db.inputCollection.aggregate([{$addFields:{Note:{$reduce:{input:{$split:["$Note","\n"]}, initialValue:"", in:{$concat:["$$value","$$this"]}}}}},{$out:"outputCollection"}])
```

Breaking this down:

`$addFields` will add new fields to every document, replacing any with the same name
Set `Note` field to the result of `$reduce`
for input to the reduce, create an array by splitting the`Note` field on newline  `{$split:["$Note","\n"]}`
the `in` field of the reduce specifies the function `{$concat:["$$value","$$this"]}` this concatenates the current value after the previous
This stage in the pipeline is roughly equivalent to .split("/n").join("")

`$out` writes the output to the collection name, ready for you to export

If it is OK to modify the original collection, you might update that field with:

```
db.inputCollection.find({Note:/\n/},{Note:1}).forEach(function(d){  
  db.inputCollection.update({_id:d._id},{$set:{Note:d.Note.replace(/\n/g, '')}})
})
```

Comment: I am not allowed to modify the original collection but your approach makes the most sense at this point. I have modified my code to do a replace like this

`....while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  var record = cursor.next();
  print(
...
    "\"" + record.Note.replace(/\r\n//g, '') + "\"|" ....`